# PHP Mongo query not returning expected results

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using the latest php mongo driver along with the latest mongodb 2.0. I'm trying to run a base query of host=x return the results then refine the search with other terms.

It's not returning any valid results.

I was thinking something like this, but its obviously not working:

```
$basefilter = array('host' => new MongoRegex("/1.1.1.1|2.2.2.2/i"));
$filter = array('host' => new MongoRegex("/2.2.2.2/i"));
$basereturn = $collection->find($basefilter);
$initreturn = $basereturn->find($filter);
$return = $initreturn->sort(array('date' => -1))->limit($limit)->skip($skip);
```

I want to just be able to refine my search. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a find over a cursor. find only works over collections. I suspect the above fatals out. You can map/reduce into a collection and run find on it.

Answer (score 0):

you probably should scape your regex you have there since the dot is an operator in regex, so that should have been:

```
$basefilter = array('host' => new MongoRegex("/(1\.1\.1\.1)|(2\.2\.2\.2)/i"));
```